# How to run summarytools::freq() in a group instead on a variable by itself?

Tags: r, frequency

I wrote this to run multiple frequencies at one time:

```
freq(staff[ ,c("hispanic","race","county","disabled",
              "ethnicity","frail","funding","funding1","funding2","gender",
              "language","marital","office","outcome","problem")])
```

it ran all but 4 of them, telling me it was ignoring variables:

```
Variable(s) ignored: county, funding, funding1, problem
```

So then i ran them separately one at a time, without a problem.  Any ideas on why they can't be included in the larger group?  `"county"` is character, but `"funding"`, `"funding1"`, and `"problem"` are all factors.  AND, it will run `"funding2"` (also a factor) in the group.

So then i tried running the four troublemakers by themselves:

```
freq(staff[ ,c("county", "funding", "funding1", "problem")])
```

and got this:

```
Error in x[[1]] : subscript out of bounds
```

Everything is stored in a `"tbl_df"` is that helps.

Comment: Do you still have that issue? If so, you can try installing a more recent version from github with devtools or remotes (`remotes::install_github("dcomtois/summarytools")`). If still experiencing the same issue, I invite you to open an issue [here](https://github.com/dcomtois/summarytools/issues)

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue which should have been resolved by now, but in case others run into a similar issue, check out the `freq.ignore.threshold` option (set using `st_options()`) which determines the number of distinct values above which a numerical variable will be ignored. (Character variables and factors are not affected by this, so this is not what caused the problem the OP raised).

To include all variables, could simply set this option to a very high number, if this is really what you want:

```
library(summarytools)
st_options(freq.ignore.threshold = 999999)
```

In the upcoming version (0.9.7), using `Inf` will also be allowed. For some reason, `checkmate::test_int` doesn't seem to accept `Inf` despite documentation stating the contrary, so a little hack will be necessary.

```
library(summarytools)
st_options(freq.ignore.threshold = Inf)
```